# How to solve the error "no instance of (something::something) matches the argument list"?

Tags: c++, inheritance, arguments

I was in a middle of doing my assignment, and it is almost done when I encounter this issue.

I was creating an array of data and allow the user to interact with it.

```
Mammal* mammal[3] = { new Dog("Puppy",Blue,"Cindy"), new Cat("Kitty",Black,"Wai"), new Lion("Simba",Brown,"Ryo")};
```

Let's just use one member.

```
new Dog("Puppy",Blue,"Cindy")
```

I have a header code section written as follows:

```
using namespace std;
enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown };
class Animal {
private:
    string _name;
    COLOR _color;
public:
    Animal(string n, COLOR c);

    virtual void speak() = 0;
    virtual void move() = 0;
    virtual void eat() = 0;
};

class Mammal :public Animal {
public:
    Mammal(string n, COLOR c);
    void speak();
    void move();
    void eat();

};

class Dog : public Mammal {
private:
    string _owner;
public:
    Dog(string n, COLOR c, string o);
    ~Dog();

    void speak() override;
    void move() override;
};
```

In the cpp file, I have created some codes for speak() and move() to override the superclass'.

```
Dog::Dog(string n, COLOR c, string o) : Mammal(n, c), _owner(o) {}
Dog::~Dog()
{
}
void Dog::speak() {
    cout << "Woof" << endl;
}

void Dog::move() {
    cout << "Dog is moving" << endl;
}
```

I expected no errors, but then I got this error.

E0289 no instance of constructor "Dog::Dog" matches the argument list   argument types are: (const char [6], color, const char [6])

All of this was written using VS2019. Have I missed something?

Comment: The error is mirrored with Cat and Lion as well, and all their own overriding codes are similar.

Comment: `Dog::~Dog()
{
}` - Don't do that. Do `~Dog() = default;` in the class declaration instead, and get a trivial destructor rather than a user defined one.

Comment: Still doesn't fix the issue, any other comments?

Comment: you are using color in small letter at color _color=Green; does this correct?

Comment: also is the error message says COLOR or color?

Comment: just color, all small, that's what it says

Comment: @RyoTanada That comment was not intended to fix your issue, just to point out some inefficiency and bad style.

Comment: I just edited the code, now it's COLOR.

Comment: Your code compiles in VS2019 when I try (but I can't link/run without full ctor stuffs for `Mammal` and `Animal`).

Comment: I just realized what's the issue. The cpp file has a redundant enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown };

Comment: But I put it all into one file! Maybe you have some definition of `color` (lowercase) in your cpp file?